# Is it possible to link existing containers with docker?

Tags: docker

Can I create a container using `docker run <image>` without the `--link` option and link other containers to it afterwards? If so, how do I link these containers then?

Answer (score 3):

Thats how you normally would do it. Fire up container A and start container B with `--link B:resourcename`. Inside container B, you can now get to the stuff container A `EXPOSE`s, with the info you can see inside the environment-variables `env` (they will be named something with `resourcename` in this case.

You can not do this the other way around (as I thought your question was originally about). The information the container needs to get to resources on the other is available as environment-variables. Which you cant inject into a running process (as far as I know..).

Comment: So is it not possible to link two existing containers? can I only do the linking when creating a new container with a `docker run <image> --link` call?

Comment: Links a currently static, you may follow this proposal: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7468 for evolutions on that matter.

Comment: `--link` is now deprecated. You might want to read up on this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes,but you can only access other containers by ip (usually 172.17.1.x).
You can use

```
docker inspect container_id
```

to find other containers ip.

Comment: Just voted you up.. If anyone is voting this down, please explain in the comments why you are doing so. This solved my problem. I understand why it might not be a best practice, but if needed you can use this.

Comment: This fixes the problem for me also, :)

Comment: The question was how to link containers. This answer says how you can inspect a container, so does not answer the question.